# Term Store Management and Site Collections

Tags: sharepoint-server, taxonomy, managed-metadata-service

First, the background... When I go into Site Settings from the SharePoint website I have inherited (which I will henceforth call "x-spweb" when referencing its internal address, or "sp.foo.com" for external) and click on the Term Store Management link, I only see a local Site Collection with the address of the SharePoint front-end at https://sp.foo.com...

[image: FRONT-END TAXANOMY TERM STORE]

When I go into Central Administration, the address bar indicates it is running from the app server (which I will call "x-spapp"), and when I go into Manage service applications->Managed Metadata Service it shows nothing *specifically* labelled "Site Collection" (and I do understand that the local "Site Collection -sp.foo.com" is local to sp.foo.com which is why it doesn't show in Central Administration, but I'll get back to this later)...

[image: CENTRAL ADMIN TAXANOMY TERM STORE]

When I go into the Taxonomy Hidden List via https://sp.foo.com/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList I see terms that are just that... hidden... they aren't listed anywhere that the Term Management Tool will let me access. But if I go into a library and create a Managed Metadata column and set it to "Use a managed term set: Find term sets that include the following terms" and search for a term that I know is in the Taxonomy Hidden List ("oceania"), I can see that the system finds the term in "**Site Collection - x-spapp**"...

[image: ADD COLUMN]

I was able to figure out how to get the PowerShell to export the term store into CSV files by individual termsets, but I can't figure out how I can either import them back in to the term store, or manually add terms into the termsets (for example into the Region termset under Site Collection - x-spapp) using the Term Store Management Tool.

So my question *finally* is: how do I add to/modify "Site Collection - x-spapp"?